imported ACF from rest api not show in post
i'm trying to create post from wordpress rest API. I have a custom post type books and fields for this post type.
My custom endpoint is /wp-json/wp/v2/books and work good for POST and GET Methods.
The code in my node.js are:
async function createBook(item) {
  const postData = {
    title: item.title,
    content: "",
    status: "publish",
    type: "books",
    acf: {
      pages: item.pages,

    },
  };

  try {
    const response = await axios.post(`${URL}/books`, postData, {
      headers,
    });
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error creating post with ACF data:", error);
    throw error;
  }
}

And this code create new post with acf data and the output look like this
"acf": {
        "pages": "143",
    },

The problem is this value not show in field when open the post for edit. The filed is empty.
When i try to put the value direct in filed (from edit post page) the value is show in edit post page, but not show in rest api GET.
